# There can be AJAX behavior even when the URL changes in browser?

Tags: ajax, browser

If using the current Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, when switching between

> http://www.facebook.com/my_name
>      http://www.facebook.com

The side panel for feed and chat, and any chat box actually stays.  I thought when the URL changes, the page *has to* refresh as a whole, but obviously, this is not the case here.  How is that done?

On IE 9, the URL actually became `http://www.facebook.com/#!` and using the "hash" to do ajax without refreshing the page, which is more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the URL and page history from javascript without actually reloading the page.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/401728) on another question.

Note, that if you type the new URL by yourself and press enter the whole page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

this might be the internal linking in the webpage with hidden DIVs with IDs and onClick those Hidden DIVs get visible with javascript and with AJAX content is loaded it will be a good if you browse the site disabling javascipt